# ITimeouts.SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan) is obsolete - Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor-net

I used script to handle wait for `AngularJS` processing, and `SetScriptTimeout` (as below code) and after update to selenium 3.2.0 , I am getting following warning

> ITimeouts.SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan) is obsolete ........., Please set
>   the AsynchronousJavaScript property instead

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
```

How to solve this warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SetScriptTimeout()`, as well as `ImplicitlyWait()` and `SetPageLoadTimeout()` will be removed in future `Selenium` versions. In the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteTimeouts.cs) you can see it has `Obsolete` annotation

```
[Obsolete("This method will be removed in a future version. Please set the AsynchronousJavaScript property instead.")]
```

Change it to

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
```